# How to configure multiple index.html files corresponding to different views using Grunt in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I'm using angularjs and want to configure Gruntfile for the following task-
Currently I'm having 1 index.html, 1 main.css and 1 script.js files in Grunt configuration. I want to modify the Grunt configuration for the different views (say, lecture1, lecture2,...) so that each view have it's own index.html, css and script file. e.g. For lecture1, I want to make index1.html, main1.css, script1.js. For lecture2, index2.html, main2.css and script2.css and so on...
I will be creating multiple index.html files and include the link tag inside

```
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/main2.css -->
// links to css files
<!-- endbuild -->
```

and include the script files -

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
// some script files
<!-- endbuild -->
```

How can we configure the Gruntfile.js for the same.
Here's my Gruntfile looks like -
https://gist.github.com/pratikmakune3/5901f1bce949444d8f0c8d5b1f796681

Comment: Basically I want to make Multipage application in angularjs

Comment: In that case, you need to code the application using angularjs. Grunt has a very different purpose. It has nothing to do with your requirement.

Comment: @PrerakSola, So you mean, I have to re-structure the angular modules accordingly, Grunt configurations won't help in such case ?